# Highlight Table Rows in Multiple tables on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I have three tables, all side by side to allow for an overflow.

I need the table rows on all three tables to be linked so when it is hovered on one table that row is highlighted throughout all the tables.

Would really appreciate any help.

Example:

```
<table class="one" width="33.3%">
  <tr>
    <td>Example</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="two" width="33.3%">
  <tr>
     <td>Example</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="three" width="33.3%">
  <tr>
    <td>Example</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use jquery's hover method in combination with nth-child selectors.

```
$("#parentDiv table tr").hover(function(){
    // on enter
    var childNum = $(this).index() + 1;
    $('#parentDiv table tr:nth-child('+childNum+')').css("background-color", "pink");
    }, function(){
    // on leave
    var childNum = $(this).index() + 1;
    $('#parentDiv table tr:nth-child('+childNum+')').css("background-color", "white");
});
```

Change #parentDiv to whatever you have as a common parent element for the tables you need highlighted.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/z7r8oc57/

Comment: Thanks for this! It's working but it highlights all the table rows, not just the row that I'm hovering.

Comment: I changed it. Using the nth-child selector it should work.